Was this student's ejection from her PhD legitimate?
A lady named Lakshmi Balakrishnan from India is preparing to file a case against Oxford University.

Help Seek Justice from Oxford for Plagiarism and Racism

Indian student spent Rs 1 crore on PhD, 'forcibly removed' by Oxford in fourth year



Dear Friends,
The University of Oxford has committed an injustice most foul!
Please lend me your ears as I recount my harrowing experiences in this historic institution.
BREACH OF CONTRACT:
Coming from the small town of Madurai in south India, it was truly a dream come true for me when I received the offer from Oxford in 2018 to pursue my PhD on Shakespeare in the English Faculty.
The offer letter gave me the supervisor of my choice, who is an expert on Shakespeare. After I paid my tuition fees and joined Oxford, the University BREACHED THE CONTRACT of my offer letter by appointing a supervisor who does not have even a single publication on Shakespeare and who was also painfully negligent. Despite my pleas, the University refused to address this problem.
Things took a turn for the worse in November 2021 during the fourth year of my PhD studies, by which time I had spent an exorbitant sum of £100,000. My Oxford dream turned into a nightmare when my examiners failed my internal assessment known as the ‘Confirmation of Status’—not due to any shortcoming on my part, but because SHAKESPEARE apparently does not have ‘SCOPE’ for doctoral-level studies!
Well before joining Oxford, I clearly stated in my application that my PhD thesis is on Shakespeare. The ‘scope’ of my thesis has always remained the same since the time of my application. Besides, the assessment rules clearly state that evaluating the ‘scope’ of a thesis is the purpose of having an exam in the first year of PhD studies known as the ‘Transfer of Status’. I had already passed that exam in June 2019 and my previous assessors had already formally approved the ‘scope’ and ‘validity’ of my PhD thesis.
CANCELLING SHAKESPEARE AT OXFORD:
In a letter to His Majesty King Charles III, who is a lover of Shakespeare, I unravelled the cultural underpinnings of this strange decision of the assessors at Oxford:
“This astonishing proclamation that Shakespeare does not have ‘scope’ for doctoral-level study is only the culmination of the symptoms of a deeper cultural malaise of systemic cancellation of Shakespeare that seems to have been allowed to afflict this great institution for quite a while now. An example of this long-standing symptom would be: once we arrive at Oxford, we learn it is an open secret that any implication of Shakespeare being ‘unique’, ‘universal’, or ‘timeless’ in our work would be met with scorn, scepticism, and serious negative consequences in academic progression (two of my own assessment reports being cases in point, as they carry subtle warnings against this implication). In the English Faculty’s Renaissance seminar events, Shakespeare is systemically marginalized.
… Curiously, the assessors did not have a problem with the central argument of my doctoral thesis per se. The problem, as they saw it, is that I committed the original sin of choosing to ‘focus’ on Shakespeare in the first place. They concluded their report by plainly reasoning that Shakespeare does not have ‘scope’ for doctoral study.”
ACADEMIC BULLYING, PLAGIARISM, AND RACISM:
Experts worldwide have testified on record that my PhD research is ‘ground-breaking’, ‘field-changing’, ‘bold, interesting and impressive’.
So, why then is the University refusing to rectify this manifestly unjust decision? All the evidence points to PLAGIARISM by Faculty, followed by BULLYING and HARASSMENT, all aimed at protecting the theft of my intellectual property.
In addition, there is also evidence of RACISM and DISCRIMINATION in regard to the PhD exam, as well as the procedural irregularities involved in my case. The assessors used the prevalent trend of cancelling Shakespeare at Oxford to discriminate against me—for the very same assessors have approved the white students’ PhD theses on Shakespeare.
LEGAL ACTION:
Over the past two and a half years, I submitted several appeals and complaints since December 2021 to the University and the Office of the Independent Adjudicator (OIA) and pleaded with them to allow me to submit my PhD thesis and have my final viva, but to no avail. Throughout, the University has absurdly maintained that the assessors are ‘credited scholars of Shakespeare’ and that if they decide that Shakespeare does not have ‘scope’ for doctoral studies, then their ‘academic judgement’ must be accepted. The appeals and complaints processes appear to be a complete sham.
I have no choice now but to seek justice by taking legal action against the University, and I seek your kind support to fight this gross injustice.
HELP UPHOLD ACADEMIC INTEGRITY, EQUALITY, AND FAIRNESS AT OXFORD:
International students currently pay nearly thrice more than British students for tuition fees. Degrees are the sole motivation for us to spend such an exorbitant sum of money and come to Oxford.
Hailing from an underprivileged background, my journey to Oxford was marked by immense sacrifices—including by selling all the properties at my disposal and expending all the savings to meet the £100,000 PhD costs. After all this, if Oxford denies me the PhD based on such an egregiously arbitrary and whimsical excuse as Shakespeare not having ‘scope’ for doctoral studies, it is not only inhumanely unfair, but it also sets a dangerous precedent for Oxford to exploit and mistreat other students as well. Given all the important issues at stake here, helping me in my fight for justice will also ensure a fairer and safer academic environment for everyone.
As Oxford’s betrayal has sabotaged my academic career, affected my job prospects, and rendered me destitute, I earnestly seek your financial support to pursue legal action and sustain myself. Any contributions, large or small, will make an enormous difference for my cause.
Thank you so much for your solidarity!

I am not a humanities or literature person.
Can you tell me in layman's terms why Oxford University expelled her from the PhD program?
Has she been a victim of racism, or is she blowing things out of proportion?

Your first question "Can you tell me in layman's terms why Oxford University expelled her from the PhD program?" may be on topic here. Of course, the lengthy quote you give ("my examiners failed my internal assessment known as the ‘Confirmation of Status’—not due to any shortcoming on my part, but because SHAKESPEARE apparently does not have ‘SCOPE’ for doctoral-level studies") gives only one side of the picture, and Oxford U may have quite a different view - which in turn they may or may not make public, so it may be hard to even get the other side's view.

Your second question "Has she been a victim of racism, or is she blowing things out of proportion?" is opinion-based and thus off-topic. Especially since presumably nobody here is privy to the internal workings of her examinations at Oxford. I would suggest you remove this second question, and very much cut down the quote; most of it is irrelevant to your first question. (And your post may still be closed as off-topic.)

I do not think it is appropriate to bring a specific person's case here.

Possibly relevant (and less one-sided) BBC article on the topic.

She has exhausted the appeals process. The dismissal is legitimate under Oxford’s rules. You may not like the outcome, true.

Should have a label: "Asking for a friend"

In the second link you gave, there's this paragraph:

Lakshmi Balakrishnan, who already has two masters degree[s], was told by the assessors that her Shakespeare research wasn't a PhD level work, thus failing her in her fourth year.
"They forcibly removed me from the PhD program and moved me to a masters level course without my consent", she said.

The link goes on to say:

"To achieve Confirmation of Status, progress must sufficiently demonstrate a strong likelihood of successful completion of a doctoral thesis. Unfortunately, not all students achieve this.

When you enroll in a PhD course, you'll have to meet certain milestones. One very common expectation is, sometime soon after enrollment (order of magnitude is ~1 year in for British-style programs, as far as I'm aware) you'll produce a progress report that says This is what my thesis is going to be about, this is how I'm going to answer the research question, and this is the expected timeline. This repeats every year. This is what I have discovered, this is what I'm going to do next, and this is the expected timeline.
If the student is not progressing well, then a poor progress report is when the department will notice and intervene. Usually they'll see what they can do to help the student get back on track, although if that doesn't work out then they'll take more dramatic actions (like downgrade the student to a Masters student).
Presumably what happened is that the people who read her progress report felt that Lakshmi Balakrishnan has not been doing research at PhD level and her thesis is not likely to pass. Accordingly, they recommended she be moved to a Masters student (the alternative is probably to fail out without a degree). Note this means that they think her research has some merit - it's just that the work is not advanced enough for a PhD. She didn't agree with this decision so she filed an appeal, which was handled by another group of people ("Office of Independent Adjudicator"). This group agreed with the assessment that her thesis is not at PhD level and is not likely to pass a defense.
As for whether she's a victim of racism: this is hard to tell from the outside; you'd need internal details. Still, it does not look like her case is a strong one. E.g. she writes:

This astonishing proclamation that Shakespeare does not have ‘scope’ for doctoral-level study is only the culmination ...

I'd be surprised if you can write a thesis on Shakespeare. That's too broad. You can presumably write a thesis on one specific aspect of Shakespeare's work. She appears not to have listed her research question in detail (why?).

So, why then is the University refusing to rectify this manifestly unjust decision? All the evidence points to PLAGIARISM by Faculty, followed by BULLYING and HARASSMENT, all aimed at protecting the theft of my intellectual property.

Alleging plagiarism here would suggest that the faculty has published something using her ideas, without crediting her. If so, she should be able to link the alleged plagiarized work, which she hasn't done.

Over the past two and a half years, I submitted several appeals and complaints since December 2021 to the University and the Office of the Independent Adjudicator (OIA) and pleaded with them to allow me to submit my PhD thesis and have my final viva, but to no avail.

What would be the point? If her advisors don't believe her work is PhD-level, then she could have a final viva, but she'd fail, so it'd be a waste of time. It'd merely move the complaint to "they let me have a defense and then failed me".
Finally, the argument "I have spent £100,000 for a PhD and now I'm getting a Masters degree" is very off-putting. You don't get a PhD by buying it. You still have to do the work (and do it well). The amount of money she spent is irrelevant.
However: I don't have an internal view of Oxford, and she didn't describe her research question (and even if she had I'm no expert on Shakespeare). There are also at least two professors who think her work is PhD level. So it's possible her complaint has merit; I simply don't know, and probably nobody except those with direct knowledge of the process do.

It also looks very suspicious that she claims that "Experts worldwide have testified on record that my PhD research is ‘ground-breaking’, ‘field-changing’, ‘bold, interesting and impressive’", but does not name any of these experts.

And applying those term to Shakespeare is really hard. Perhaps if you discovered a new play by him…
